# datamaps.js: Animate bubble remove after new data gets loaded

Tags: d3.js

When we update new data on .bubbles([]) all the previous bubble disappears immediately. Can we make the bubble remain there for some time and then remove them from the map using jquery animation and also display a new bubbles at certain time periods?

Below is the code:
    
    
    `

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 600px"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bombMap = new Datamap({
        element: document.getElementById('container'),
        fills: {
            'USA': '#1f77b4',
            'RUS': '#9467bd',
            'PRK': '#ff7f0e',
            'PRC': '#2ca02c',
            'IND': '#e377c2',
            'GBR': '#8c564b',
            'FRA': '#d62728',
            'PAK': '#7f7f7f',
            defaultFill: '#c1b9bb' //any hex, color name or rgb/rgba value
        },
        geographyConfig: {
            highlightOnHover: false,
            popupOnHover: false
        },
        scope: 'world',
        data: {
            'RUS': {fillKey: 'RUS'},
            'PRK': {fillKey: 'PRK'},
            'PRC': {fillKey: 'PRC'},
            'IND': {fillKey: 'IND'},
            'GBR': {fillKey: 'GBR'},
            'FRA': {fillKey: 'FRA'},
            'PAK': {fillKey: 'PAK'},
            'USA': {fillKey: 'USA'}
        },
         bubbleConfig: {
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
            popupOnHover: false,
            fillOpacity: 0.45,
            highlightOnHover: true,
            highlightFillColor: '#FC8D59',
            highlightBorderColor: 'rgba(250, 15, 160, 0.2)',
            highlightBorderWidth: 2,
            highlightFillOpacity: 0.85,
        }
    });

     var bombs = [{
        name: 'Joe 4',
        radius: 10,
        yeild: 400,
        country: 'USSR',
        fillKey: 'RUS',
        significance: 'First fusion weapon test by the USSR (not "staged")',
        date: '1953-08-12',
        latitude: 50.07,
        longitude: 78.43
      },{
        name: 'RDS-37',
        radius: 10,
        yeild: 1600,
        country: 'USSR',
        fillKey: 'RUS',
        significance: 'First "staged" thermonuclear weapon test by the USSR (deployable)',
        date: '1955-11-22',
        latitude: 50.07,
        longitude: 78.43

      },
    ];

    var options = {
        popupTemplate: function (geo, data) { 
                return ['<div class="hoverinfo">' +  data.name,
                '<br/>Payload: ' +  data.yeild + ' kilotons',
                '<br/>Country: ' +  data.country + '',
                '<br/>Date: ' +  data.date + '',
                '</div>'].join('');
        }
    };

    bombMap.bubbles(bombs, options);
    setInterval(function(){
        console.log('removing elements');
        bombMap.bubbles([{
        name: 'Tsar Bomba',
        radius: 10,
        yeild: 50000,
        country: 'USSR',
        fillKey: 'RUS',
        significance: 'Largest thermonuclear weapon ever tested—scaled down from its initial 100 Mt design by 50%',
        date: '1961-10-31',
        latitude: 73.482,
        longitude: 54.5854
      }]);
    },3000);
</script>
```

Source: https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps

Comment: I don't see at a glance an easy way to make it happen with this library.  Open an issue on github requesting the feature.  It's possible it already exists but isn't documented.  It would be an easy change in the d3 code, but not so easy if you don't want to mess around with the library's internal code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do this by using d3 to select all the current circles (bubbles) that are on your datamap. You can then use a d3 transition to fade your circles to a fill-opacity of 0.0001 before loading your new array of bubbles.